# xticks only applying to 1 graph

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to change the x axis for my graphs but it's only going through for one of them. My other graph has not changed at all. Here is the code:

```
fig, (gr0, gr1) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, constrained_layout=True, figsize = (17,7))

#gr0 
gr0.plot(data['g1'])
gr0.set_title('text 1')

#gr1
gr1.plot(data['g2'])
gr1.set_title('text 2')

plt.xticks(fontsize=8, rotation=45)

plt.show()
```

Graphs when the code is ran:
[image]

As you can tell by the picture, only the graph on the right has the x-axis updated to where the text is rotated and clearly visible. The other one is still the same :(

Answer (score 3):

You can set it per axis using `ax.tick_params(labelsize=8, labelrotation=45)`.

```
ig, (gr0,gr1) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, constrained_layout=True, figsize = (17,7))

#gr0 
gr0.plot(data['g1'])
gr0.set_title('text 1')
gr0.tick_params(labelsize=8, labelrotation=45)

#gr1
gr1.plot(data['g2'])
gr1.set_title('text 2')
gr1.tick_params(labelsize=8, labelrotation=45)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The

```
plt.xticks(..., rotation=45)
```

call might *feel* like it applies to the whole figure,
when it's phrased that way.
But behind the scenes it's really making a `gca()` call
and manipulating that, which of course is `gr1` at that point.

You *could* make a pair of xticks calls,
much as you're already doing for title.
But the fact that you asked about this plot's behavior on SO
indicates that the way it's phrased is not a good match
for clearly communicating the intent.
So let's re-phrase it slightly, avoiding that global.

```
labels = [
    '2022-05-21',
    '2022-05-25',
    '2022-05-29',
]
gr0.set_xticks(labels=labels, rotation=45)
gr1.set_xticks(labels=labels, rotation=45)
```

Or consider moving to `import seaborn`.
In which case the idiom would be the somewhat simpler

```
gr0.grid.set_xticklabels(rotation=45)
gr1.grid.set_xticklabels(rotation=45)
```